# How can I get these elements on the same line?

Tags: html, css, inline

I have links and a sprite image I want to render in one line centered vertically:

HTML:

```
<a href="/videos/12" class="normal video_title">Why Eminem is the best</a>
<div class="sprite" id="pointer"></div>
by
<a href="/profiles/1" class="feed_image"><img alt="Justin meltzer" src="/system/photos/1/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1305874692"></a>
<a href="/profiles/1" class="normal squeeze">Justin Meltzer</a>
```

How would I get all of these elements on one line?

I'd do a jsfiddle but I don't have my sprite images at a public url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your div to display inline-block so that everything will stay on one line. Do you want the links to then be aligned with the center of the image?

http://jsfiddle.net/gUrc9/

```
div.sprite { background: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px; display: inline-block; }
```

UPDATE:
As pointed out in comments inline-block is not supported in IE6/7 unless the element it is applied to is [naturally inline](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html). So better solution would be to change div to span.

```
span.sprite { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Did thought of that, but then inline-block won't work on IE6,7. Though thr is cross-browser fix here, but that is only additional css. You are better off with starting on the right note. DIV doesn't help the cause here.

Comment: Agreed that he should probably be using an element that is inline by default, such as span as suggested by you. IE 6/7 support inline-block as long as the original element is inline by default. At least according to QuirksMode. I will update my answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to set your pointer div to be displayed inline:

```
#pointer { display: inline;}
```

By default div tags are block-level elements. This will force them inline with the rest of the items.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with one improvement. DIVs are displayed as block, so if u r using a sprite, u wud give it a width n height anyway, in that case go for SPAN.

Now wrap a div around them and give it a style:`text-align: center;`. Or you could also give this outer DIV a width. and do a `margin: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a `<span>` for the pointer - a `<div>` is for grouping related elements - which this doesn't. It will also sit on the same line automatically, becasue a span is an inline element.